# If you encrypt an entire USB with Veracrypt can malware be put on the USB while encrypted?

Tags: malware, usb-drive, badusb

Let's say that you take a USB drive and encrypt the entire thing with Veracrypt. Could someone modify that USB drive to include malware on it?  This is not assuming that physical changes to the device have been made.

Comment: Malware is irrelevant to the scenario. The question you want to ask is "is the USB drive writable?" Do you mean the firmware? On the Veracrypt volume? Where? What kind of "modification" are you imagining? You've tagged this with Badusb. Is that in scope? Are you aware of how that works? Else we could simply say "yes, with badusb" but I'm getting the impression that you have more in mind than that.